# Remove blur effect from UIVisualEffectView

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uivisualeffectview

How to remove blur effect from UIVisualEffectView control in xamarin.ios. I don't want that effect. I just want to keep it simple.

Answer (score -1):

**UIVisualEffectView** inherits from **UIView**.

So, if you don't need the blur effect, you can just set the `Hidden` property of `UIVisualEffectView` to `true`.

```
visualEffectView.Hidden = true;
```

Also, you can set it back when you need the effect again.